# Tailwind width and height are not applied to the inner element

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

For some unknown reason, the child element is not getting the height and width of its parent:

```
<div class="h-10 w-10">
    <div class="w-full h-full"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my `style.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layout utilities {
    .animation-delay-1 {
        animation-delay: 1s;
    }

    .animation-delay-500 {
        animation-delay: 500ms;
    }
}
```

And here's my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        tomato: {
          400: '#FD6A5E'
        }
      },
      animation: {
        wiggle: 'wiggle 5s infinite'
      },
      keyframes: {
        wiggle: {
          '0%, 100%': {
            transform: 'translateY(0.5rem) scale(0.5)'
          },
          '50%': {
            transform: 'translateY(0) scale(0.5)'
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And this is an image of the Chrome's DevTools:

[image]

What might be the problem?

Comment: This should definitely work, unless you're adding the Tailwind classes directly in the dev tools. Example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/UGf8l3emxN What's the path to the file that contains your HTML?

Comment: @EdLucas, the parent element gets styles. As you see, `w-full` is also applying. I guess somehow tailwind's engine can't pick `h-full` style. I need to find a way to debug it.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Youzef, I had to rewrite the entire project.